# use ruby to get content length of URLs

Tags: ruby, net-http

I am trying to write a ruby script that gets some details about files on a website using `net/http`. My code looks like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI.parse asset
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.get(asset)
} 

headers = res.to_hash
p headers
```

I would like to get two pieces of information from this request: the total length of the content inflated, and (as appropriate) the length of the content deflated.

Sometimes, the headers will include a `content-length` parameter, which appears to be the gzipped length of the content. I can also approximate the inflated size of the content using res.body.length, but this has not been foolproof by any stretch of the imagination. The documentation on `net/http` says that gzip headers are removed from the list automatically (to *help* me, gee thanks) so I cannot seem to get a reliable handle on this information.

Any help is appreciated (including other gems if they will do this more easily).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! The "magic" behavior here only occurs if you don't specify your own accept-encoding header. Amended code as follows:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'date'
require 'zlib' 

headers = { "accept-encoding" => "gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3" }
url = URI.parse asset
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.get(asset, headers)
}

headers = res.to_hash

gzipped = headers['content-encoding'] && headers['content-encoding'][0] == "gzip"
content = gzipped ? Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(res.body)).read : res.body 


full_length = content.length,
compressed_length = (headers["content-length"] && headers["content-length"][0] || res.body.length),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use sockets to send HEAD request to the server with is faster (no content) and don't send "Accept-Encoding: gzip", so your response will not be gzip.