# Get size of Nokogiri XML document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to figure out how to get the size of a Nokogiri XML document. The document is being fetched with `open`:

```
 Nokogiri::XML(open(my_url))
```

Is it possible at this point to determine the size of the returned document? Are any HTTP headers retrievable such as Content-type or Content-Length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with Nokogiri directly. I you want to know the content-length before downloading the file you can do something like this:

```
response = http.request_head('http://www.example.com/file.ext')
file_size = response['content-length']
```

The file_size will be in bytes.

Comment: both ``response['content-length']`` and ``response['Content-Length']`` come up empty. any idea why? ``response['content-type']`` works just fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811829/use-ruby-to-get-content-length-of-urls that's probably your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
opened_url = open(my_url)
opened_url.size # Gets size
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(my_url))
```

When checking the "size" of a string you might want to keep in mind the discussion from this post:
http://zargony.com/2009/07/24/ruby-1-9-and-file-encodings

Comment: I like dierre's answer a lot more than mine.